# How to filter an empty list? Many to many relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I filter as follows:

```
queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('level', queryset=Level.objects.filter(id=level)))
```

In this case, empty lists remain:

```
{
   ...
    "level": []
   ...
},
{
    ...
    "level": [
        2
    ]
    ...
}
```

I tried to filter like this:

```
queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('level',queryset=Level.objects.filter(id=level).exclude(id__isnull=True)))
```

But it didn't help.

I also want to know if it is possible to get a value without lists?

```
{
    ...
    "level": 2
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not filter on the `Prefetch` object, since then it is "too" late. Then you filter out *elements*. You should filter the `queryset` with:

```
queryset.filter(level=level).prefetch_related(
     Prefetch('level', queryset=Level.objects.filter(id=level)))
)
```

You can furthermore annotate the value of `Level`, and then use that as a field:

```
from django.db.models import F

queryset.filter(level=level).annotate(
    level_value=F('level')
)
```

Then in the serializer, you can use an `IntegerField` for example that takes as `source='level_value'`:

from rest_framework import serializers

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    level = IntegerField(source='level_value')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```